# I can't get data from database using cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

**I have make following function for getting data.**

```
public List<Presentation> getSlideMaster() {

        List<Presentation> pptList = new ArrayList<Presentation>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "
                + Constants.SLIDE_MASTER.slideMaster_Table + " WHERE dm_Id=" + lastDeckID;

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Presentation presentation = new Presentation();
                presentation.setSlideId(cursor.getString(0));
                getSlideID = presentation.getSlideId();
                Log.i("string slide id in database helper", "" + presentation.getSlideId());

                pptList.add(presentation);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        String selectQuery2 = "SELECT sl_Id FROM "
                + Constants.SLIDE_LAYOUT.slideLayout_Table + " WHERE sm_Id = "
                + getSlideID;
        Cursor cursorSL = db.rawQuery(selectQuery2, null);
        Log.i("query", ""+selectQuery2);
        if(cursorSL.moveToFirst()){
            Log.i("getslideLayout function", "");
            do{

                Log.i("query string 0 ", ""+cursorSL.getString(0));
                Presentation presentation = new Presentation();
                presentation.setSlideLayoutId(cursorSL.getString(0));
                getSlideLayoutId  = presentation.getSlideLayoutId();

                Log.i("string slide layout id in slideMaster", "" + getSlideLayoutId);
            }while(cursorSL.moveToNext());
        }
        else{
            Log.i("No Data Found!!!!!", "");
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursorSL.close();
        db.close();
        return pptList;

    }
```

**I getting data from slideMaster_Table very fine and easily but I can't get data from another query, which is not print any value in Logcat inside of if(cursorSL.moveToFirst()) condition**
[image: This is SlideLayout_table]

**When I use code in another activity i can get sl_Id very easily.**

Comment: Check whether your `cursorSL` is empty or not, using `getCount()` method of `Cursor` class.

Comment: use `Cursor cursorSL = db.rawQuery(selectQuery2, new String[]{getSlideID});` for selectQuery2="SELECT sl_Id FROM "+Constants.SLIDE_LAYOUT.slideLayout_Table + " WHERE sm_Id = ?";

Comment: @MM-BB, thanks but this is not working for me.

Comment: Show us the contents of the table and the return value of `getSlideID`.

Comment: I added image of database.return value of getSlideID is last column sm_Id and i want sl_Id.

Answer (score 0):

may below solution solve your problem

use `Cursor cursorSL = db.rawQuery(selectQuery2, new String[]{getSlideID});`

for

`selectQuery2="SELECT sl_Id FROM "+Constants.SLIDE_LAYOUT.slideLayout_Table + " WHERE sm_Id = ?";`

Comment: thanks but this is not working for me.nothing to be printed inside of if condition.

Comment: **this is not working..Any solution for this small problem?**

Answer (score 0):

My speculation is that you have troubles constructing the second query. Basically it is never a good idea to construct database queries like you do. The android database API is providing more accurate interface for that. Rewrite your second part of program to:

```
String [] selectArgs = {getSlideID};
String selectQuery2 = "sm_Id = ?";
Cursor cursorSL = db.query(Constants.SLIDE_LAYOUT.slideLayout_Table, null,
                           selectQuery2, selectArgs, null, null, null, null);
```

Note that the fourth parameter of [`query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is meant for substitution of where arguments, it is `String[]` and all the array members are substituted in sequence in the places of ? in the query string.

I think you might be facing problem with constructing the query.

---

**PS:** You are also misusing the log tags:

```
Log.i("No Data Found!!!!!", "");
```

Should actually be `Log.i("TAG", "No Data Found!!!!!");`

The first parameter is log tag and is supposed to be used for grouping related log messages, in your case you print every message in its own group, which does not make much sense.

I know this note will not solve your immediate problem, but I am pointing it out, so that you will know it for the future (I also suffer from seeing colleagues of mine learning from SO wrong practises like that one).

Comment: thanks for it.Now, I used this but nothing to be print or go inside of if condition. And other function for getting data from database is working fine but only in this table i cant get any errors or result.

Comment: **this is not working..Any solution for this small problem?**

Comment: @immodi ok, sorry was away for a little while. I will try to help. What actually happens with the second condition? Do you see `No Data Found!!!!!` printed out? Or do you see `getslideLayout function` and then `string slide layout id in slideMaster` without any value?

Comment: No..nothing is printed.I already describe that nothing to be printed or happened in IF condition...

Comment: @immodi then it should be an exception that happens can you try surrounding the method in `try\catch` and print the exception in the log? Please share the stacktrace afterwards

Comment: I get "No Data Found" in Logcat.

Comment: @immodi what does this line log: `Log.i("string slide id in database helper", "" + presentation.getSlideId());`

Comment: It returns lastest sm_Id like 19 from database.

Comment: @immodi what type is `sm_Id` in the `SLIDE_LAYOUT.slideLayout_Table`?

Comment: sm_Id has INTEGER type.

Comment: @immodi nope, no reason fro what you report. PLease verify everything you have said once again something should be nto exactly as you say. PLease also include the relevant part of the log cat verbatim

Comment: Thats reason I m shocked for this problem.When I use this code in another class then i get very easily but that class is child class.